# Host multiple domains with Apache on a VPS

Tags: php, windows, apache-2.2, hosting, domain

I have recently bought a windows VPS and installed apache, mysql using xampp. All services are running fine. I can access the hosted site using the IP of VPS but what I need to do is host multiple domains on that server.

Actually my requirement was to use htaccess on a php based site but the site had to access data from ms sql server as well. So needed to enable php_mssql.dll in the php.ini which no shared hosting was supporting. Had to go for this VPS.

Plesk was installed by default but as htaccess wont work with IIS, I had to stop IIS service and install apache there. Now all is well, but I need to find a way to host multiple domains there.

When I bought the VPS they hosting people sent me the dedicated IP of the server and also I have the 2 name servers required to host domains. What is the next step? Exactly which file I need to modify to get things done? Please help!

Any kind of help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance for all of your kind help and time.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to look at apache's virtual hosts feature. See [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/). You'll need to set up the virtual hosts with apache and also set up the DNS settings in the nameservers for each of your domains so that they're pointing to the dedicated IP address.

Comment: @Kunal: Sorry, that was an old version of the doc. I updated the link to version 2.2.

Comment: @Drackir: Thanks a lot! Let me try this and get back to you.

Comment: @Kunal: Good luck!

Comment: @Drackir: There are already so many items in the httpd.conf file. By the way  I checked in the apache/conf/httpd.conf file, hope that's what you mentioned. There are many existing entries, do I have to write the <VirtualHost *:80> inside any particular node, or just at the end of the file? Please confirm. Thanks a tonne for your valuable time.